# Deep-linking in Orbit from Another Page

Tags: zurb-foundation

On the Zurb docs pages (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) there is an example of deep linking into an orbit control from a link.  Works fine as per the example.  However, I want to deep-link from another page, i.e. I want to click on a link in a page that does not contain the orbit in question and return to the page with the orbit and slide the orbit over to a particular slide.

As per the docs I have data-orbit-slide and data-orbit-link setup but it always returns back to the first slide.

Anyone else try this?  Is it even possible?  Thanks.